# Using C++ SQLDriverConnect Connection Handle in C# as SqlConnection

Tags: c#, c++, sql, connection, dynamic-dll-import

Below code is used for SQL Connection in C++:

```
SQLDriverConnect(hdbc,    /* Connection handle */
    0,                     /* Window handle */
    connectString,         /* Connection string */
    SQL_NTS,               /* This is a null-terminated string */
    (SQLWCHAR*)NULL,       /* Output (result) connection string */
    SQL_NTS,               /* This is a null-terminated string */
    0,                     /* Length of output connect string */
    SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT); /* Don’t display a prompt window */
```

And the class below is used in C# as Data Class for SQL Connection:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon;
```

Is there any way (conversion method) to use `hdbc` as `sqlCon` in C# Code? I know we can use `DllImport` for these kind of conversions to use C++ methods in C#, but do not know is it possible also for an `SQLConnection` class.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. `SQLDriverConnect` uses ODBC drivers, but `SqlConenction` is an entirely different driver. Why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: @charlieface it is a part of work, moving code from C# to C++ to have a dll that can not be decompiled, thanks...

Comment: knowing now that "C++ to have a DLL that can not be decompiled" was an idea which is mistake...

Comment: No idea what you're trying to do, but trying to avoid decompilation is an exercise in futility